# Get Email whenever SSIS task fails

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, sql-server-2012, ssis-2008

I have one SSIS packages that has many of SQL Execute task. I want to know whether a particular task has passed or not. Is it possible for me to get email for all the tasks, to trace whether the package has failed or has passed? It would be  also helpful I can get count of rows the "SQL Execute" task has executed.

P.S. : I am running package through SQL Agent job.

Thanks

Comment: Google: `Sending email from SSIS`.

Comment: SQL Server Agent mail - https://technet.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms188235(v=SQL.105).aspx and sp_send_dbmail from BOL - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190307.aspx

Comment: for your newly added question about row counts - create a variable, add query to count number of rows and store it in the variable

Answer (score 2):

You can configure a SQL Agent job to send an email to a defined operator when a job fails (or any status you like).  All that is required is:

- Configure SQL database mail if not set up (Management -> Database mail)
- Create an Operator (SQL Server Agent -> Operators)
- Update job to send email (open job properties -> Notifications -> Check email and select operator).